# get json data in react native's TextInput

Tags: php, json, react-native

I am just a beginner so help me!

I want to get JSON response in react native TextInput.
[ i have 2 pages in react native app. 
on the first page ==> I want that JSON data and navigate to the second page with that JSON response.

I used PHP as a server-side scripting language.
My PHP code is:

```
<?php

// Importing DBConfig.php file.
include 'DBConfig.php';

// Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);

 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

// Populate column from JSON $obj array and store into $coulmn.
$firstname = $obj['firstname'];
$lastname = $obj['lastname'];
//$mobileno = $obj['mobileno'];
$email = $obj['email'];
$profession = $obj['profession'];
$mobileno = '7874853188';
//Applying User Login query with mobile number match.
$Sql_Query = "select firstname,lastname,email,profession from member where mobileno = '$mobileno' ";

// Executing SQL Query.
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));

if(isset($check)){


 $SuccessLoginMsg = 'Data Matched';

 // Converting the message into JSON format.
$SuccessLoginJson = json_encode($SuccessLoginMsg);

 $first_name = $check[0];
 $last_name = $check[1];
 $email = $check[2];
 $profession = $check[3];

// Echo the message.
 echo $SuccessLoginJson ; 
 }

 else{

 // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
$InvalidMSG = 'Enter valid phone number' ;

// Converting the message into JSON format.
$InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);

// Echo the message.
 echo $InvalidMSGJSon ;

 }

 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

above code is 100% right. [tested on the web page]

In my react native code, first I check for mobile number => if a mobile number is right[exist in the database] then that user can go to the next page with that JSON response.

[response contain 4 fields = first_name, last_name, email, response]
My JSON implementation in react native is:

```
constructor(props) { 
    super(props) 
    this.state = {

    UserMNO: ''
    } 
  }

  UserLoginFunction = () =>{

 const { UserMNO } = this.state;
 const {firstname} = this.state;
 const {lastname} = this.state;
 const {email} = this.state;
 const {profession} =this.state;

fetch('http://demo.weybee.in/react/User_Login.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({

  mobileno: UserMNO,

      })

}).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
        // If server response message same as Data Matched
       if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
        {   

            //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
            this.refs.toast.show('Login successful', 500, () => {
            const { navigation } = this.props;

            const  $firstname   = this.state ;
            const $lastname   = this.state ;
            const  $email   = this.state ;
            const  $profession   = this.state ;
            const { UserMNO }  = this.state ;

            navigation.navigate("Profile",
              {EmailId: $email,
              Name: $firstname+$lastname,
              Profe : $profession,
              mobileno : UserMNO,
              });
    });
        }
        else{

          Alert.alert(responseJson);
        }

      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

  }
```

**I enter my mobile number here:**

[image]

**My second screen [profile]- where I want my JSON response**

[image]

essential code of 2nd screen [profile]

```
<Block middle style={styles.nameInfo}>
                    <Text bold size={28} color="#32325D">
                        {this.props.navigation.getParam("Name")}
                    </Text>
                    <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="Email id"
                        value={this.props.navigation.getParam("EmailId")}
                        style={{marginTop:20, borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>
                      <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="Mobile Number"
                        value={this.props.navigation.getParam("mobileno")}
                        style={{borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>
                    <Block width={width * 0.8} style={{ marginBottom: 15 }}>
                      <Input
                        editable = {false}
                        placeholder="profession"
                        value={this.props.navigation.getParam("Profe")}
                        style={{borderRadius:30, borderWidth:3}}
                        iconContent={
                          <Icon
                            size={16}
                            color={argonTheme.COLORS.ICON}
                            name="nav-right"
                            family="ArgonExtra"
                            style={styles.inputIcons}
                          />
                        }
                      />
                    </Block>

                  </Block>
```

**Error says**:

failed prop type: invalid prop 'value' of type 'object' supplied to 'TextInput', expected 'string'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some data you receive that is not `string value`.
 You can only set the `string value` for **Textinput**. Check the value of the data received and make sure the data is `string.`

If you just want to get rid of the error,

```js
navigation.navigate("Profile",
              {EmailId: JSON.stringify($email),
              Name: JSON.stringify($firstname+$lastname),
              Profe : JSON.stringify($profession),
              mobileno : JSON.stringify(UserMNO),
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not correctly storing the information you receive in this.state

You [must call setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to store the information, and then use its values ​​with this.state.xxx

Once you store with this.setState():

```
this.setState({profe: YOUR_VALUE})
```

you should modify this:

```
value={this.state.profe}
```